# kafka stream - where is the default state store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Almost all the kafka stream doc says that it uses RocksDB for state store. I created a simple stream builder and the below example works just great. **My only confusion is - I did not specify any state store. How does it work?** . If kafka creates somewhere internally, where is it?

```
builder.stream("my-topic-1")
        .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
        .count(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
        .toStream()
        .to("my-topic-2");
```

Note: I can see the "changelog" topic in kafka. But I would like to see the default RocksDB location in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

RocksDB is only the default for persistent stores. There's also InMemoryStateStore

The default filesystem location for the persistent store is `/tmp/kafka-streams`, as of Kafka 2.7, but you can override `state.dir`

https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html

Comment: I could not see anything like that in my machine "/tmp/kafka-streams". I use mac. looks like the doc is wrong.

Comment: In-memory store is not a _persistent_ store -- it's in memory. "Persistent" indeed means written to local disk -- "persistent" does not mean fault-tolerant though, as fault-tolerance is provided via chagnelog topics and in-memory store are also fault-tolerant. -- Also, RocksDB is the default store.

Comment: The docs are indeed outdate. The default directory was `/tmp/kafka-streams` up to 2.7.0 release. Since 2.8.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10604) the default state directly is `${java.io.tmpdir}/kafka-streams` -- the effective config is logged on startup. You can also configure the state directly via `state.dir` to any location you like.

Comment: Did a PR to update the docs: https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/14155